# How to integrate Azure Policy with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, policy, azure-policy

I created the ARM templates for Azure Web App, Azure SQL Database, Key vault and Azure Storage. And deployed these ARM templates in to azure using Azure DevOps process CI and CD.

But I want to enforce policies as part of the development process. I know Microsoft released the feature of Azure Policy integration with Azure DevOps is now available. But I don’t know how to integrate policies with Azure DevOps.

Can anyone suggest me or provide any useful documentation?

Comment: All i can able to get the [release doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-policy-for-azure-devops/) which is not having any detailed docs

Comment: @Jayendran, But the above documentation doesn't contains the steps for integrating azure policies with azure devops. it just contain the updates about Azure Policy for Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 3):

After creating and assigning policies, they are automatically evaluated on every template deployment. If there is an attempt to deploy a template that violates a policy with a deny effect, you can see this in Azure DevOps:

[image]

Edit: How to use steps for creating and assigning policies and finding the output can be found on the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-policy?view=azure-devops. Also, you can now evaluate Azure Policies via an Release Gate. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-policy-check-gate?view=azure-devops

Comment: This has nothing to do with devops, just shows the cli output of test deploy cmd.

Comment: It is the way to get access to any policies that stopped template deployment, which I thought was what the asker was looking for. I just highlighted where to find the output. The same is also in the docs, I just found out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-policy?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

Azure Pipelines has Policy gates that can also be used to check if the underlying resources/resource group/subscription is compliant before proceeding.

You can find details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/azure-policy?view=azure-devops).